# What is the difference between Ring 0 and Ring 3 driver?

Tags: operating-system, driver

I'm trying to learn the basics about windows drivers.
Why I can't use functions from the header ntddk.h in a typical c++ application?

Comment: Do you already know what "the kernel" is?

Comment: I still don't know how it work very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: The *kernel* is the core component of the operating system that manages running processes, memory allocation, and so on. You can think of it as a specially privileged process - although it's not a process, because it's what manages processes.

*Kernel-mode drivers*, or *ring-0 drivers*, are loaded into the kernel. Their code is treated the same way as any other kernel code. The kernel has complete control over the system - which means that if things go wrong, it can screw up the whole system and require a reboot. (This is what a Blue Screen of Death is.)

*User-mode drivers*, or *ring-3 drivers*, run in normal processes. Like any other processes, they can't access the rest of the system without asking the kernel, and they have their own address spaces. Like with any other program, if a user-mode driver crashes, it only affects that process - and in particular, it's much less likely to cause a BSOD.

User-mode drivers also operate at a higher level of abstraction. Concepts such as IRQLs, paged/non-paged memory, and thread context don't exist outside the kernel, so the user-mode driver doesn't need to concern itself with them.

Because they run in normal processes, user-mode drivers can also be debugged with a normal debugger - a kernel debugger is not required.

The primary advantages of kernel-mode drivers are performance, and simplicity for kernel developers - this is why all drivers were originally kernel-mode. The primary advantages of user-mode drivers are isolation, security, fault tolerance, and simplicity for driver writers.

In addition, not all features are available in the User-Mode Driver Framework. [Here is a list on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn376882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - most notably, UMDF does not support Direct Memory Access, or [multiple functional power states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh451017%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

(Some information taken from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Comment: Thanks! So this header ntddk.h only works in driver development?